# Laravel auto create relation entry with default data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a wallet system in my Laravel application.

My database has the default `users` table and each user has one `wallet`.

like this:

```php
// User model
public function wallet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Wallet::class);
}
```

---

I want whenever I query `wallet` like:

```php
$user->wallet
```

I want if the user doesn't have `wallet` a new `wallet` should be created automatically with default values.

How to do this in a organized and efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "I want if the user doesn't have wallet a new wallet should be created automatically with default values" if you mean that you want some default values when using `$user->wallet` on frontend to avoid conditionals, you can use the handy `withDefault()` as below:

```php
/**
 * Get the wallet for the user.
 */
public function wallet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Wallet::class)->withDefault([
        //Default values here
        //This will not persist or create a record in database
        // It will just return an instance of Wallet with default values defined here instead of null when a user doesn't have a Wallet yet
        // It will help avoid conditionals say in frontend view
    ]);
}
```

You can read more at [DefaultModel - Lavavel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models)

However if you want every user to have a default Wallet you can make use of Model hooks and create a Wallet for each user when a record is created.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function($user){
            $user->wallet()->create([
                //Default values here...
            ]);
        });
    }

    // Rest of the User Model class code...
}
```

You can read more at [Model Events - Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I didn't even knew about this method. 
btw I also realized we can also create a entry to database with the `withDefault` method as it also accepts a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you should have a look to this

```js
//copy attributes from original model
$newRecord = $original->replicate();
// Reset any fields needed to connect to another parent, etc
$newRecord->some_id = $otherParent->id;
//save model before you recreate relations (so it has an id)
$newRecord->push();
//reset relations on EXISTING MODEL (this way you can control which ones will be loaded
$original->relations = [];
//load relations on EXISTING MODEL
$original->load('somerelationship', 'anotherrelationship');
//re-sync the child relationships
$relations = $original->getRelations();
foreach ($relations as $relation) {
    foreach ($relation as $relationRecord) {
        $newRelationship = $relationRecord->replicate();
        $newRelationship->some_parent_id = $newRecord->id;
        $newRelationship->push();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

option 1: you can use [Default Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models)

```
public function wallet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Wallet::class)->withDefault([
        'name' => 'Wallet Name',
    ]);
}
```

Option 2: insert when user created [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(static function (self $user) {
        $wallet = new Wallet(['name' => 'Wallet Name']);
        $user->wallet()->save($wallet);
    });
}
```